# Is it common to have just a return statement in a php file

Tags: php

Is it common to have just a return statement in a php file? If yes, can someone show me how this is used in other files?

```
<?php

return ['someVariable' => 'someValue'];
```

A perfect example is the config files in the Laravel framework, for instance the database.php.

Comment: Not common, but perfectly acceptable, and it can be convenient

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No it isn't very common to have just a return statement, but it is used sometimes to store the configuration information in a separate `config.php` file so that the config can be included elsewhere with php `require`.

```
//config.php
<?php

return [
    'app_key' => 'SomeRandomString',
    'app_secret' => 'SomeRandomString',
];
```

---

```
// other-file.php
<?php

$config = require 'path/to/config.php';
$facebook = new Facebook($config['app_key'], $config['app_secret']);
```

Comment: Does this work in all versions of php? If not, which version introduced it?

Comment: @CodesInChaos This has *practically* always been possible: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: @scrubmx It's better to use require without parentheses, since it's a statement and not a function. The parentheses suggest function-like behavior, which is not what you'll get (i.e. `require("a") . "b";` which will include `ab` not include `a` and concatenate its returned value with `b`).

Answer (score 15):

When an included file returns a value, `include()` or `require()` will return that value instead of the default `1`.

This isn't a *common* usage, but it is helpful in some situations, like the configuration file example you gave. (The uglier alternative, which I've seen used in many PHP applications, is to store configuration values in global variables or constants.)

Comment: An alternative, extensivelly used, is to use a static class. This has the advantage that it is present **everywhere** in the code.

Answer (score 0):

So I do something similar to this when I want to create a sort of API-like way to access data from certain php files. For instance, I might have a php file that has the following array:

```
<?php 

$cars = array(
    'Coupe' => array(
        'Make' => 'Acura',
        'Model' => 'Integra',
        'Doors' => 2,
        'HorsePower' => 150
    )
    'Sedan' => array(
        'Make' => 'Toyota',
        'Model' => 'Camry',
        'Doors' => 4,
        'HorsePower' => 115
    )
)

?>
```

I could then add something to the end of that file that digs into the `$cars` array to pull out the information I want; like in an AJAX call using javascript. You could iterate through the array to pull out the information requested. So for example, say I `POST` the parameter `Car='Coupe'`, I could then set a condition like the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['Car'])) {
    foreach($cars as $k => $type) {
        if($type == $_POST['Car']) {
            echo json_encode($type);
        }
    }
}
```

Which would output a JSON index with the `Coupe` array in it. I realize this isn't using the `return` call but it is one way I use arrays in standalone PHP files.

Comment: While this is no doubt interesting, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @duskwuff Fair enough, I figured, since he was looking for an example of how data can be returned from a standalone php file, this might be, at least, an interesting example. I zoned in too much on the array and less on the actual question. So, agreed!